# KeyError: 'mae' when plotting Keras model training progress

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm following the exact same code as shown on the [Kearas regression models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) tutorial but am unable to access the `tfdocs.plots.HistoryPlotter()` method. (New to Google Colab and TensorFlow). The rest of the cells work beside the training progress plots.

Code snippet triggering the error:

```
plotter.plot({'Basic': history}, metric = 'mae') plt.ylim([0, 10])
plt.ylabel('MAE [MPG]')
```

And the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-deee24f0bc59> in <module>()
----> 1 plotter.plot({'Basic': history}, metric = 'mae')
      2 plt.ylim([0, 10])
      3 plt.ylabel('MAE [MPG]')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_docs/plots/__init__.py in plot(self, histories, metric, smoothing_std)
     86         self.color_table[name] = color
     87 
---> 88       train_value = history.history[metric]
     89       val_value = history.history['val_' + metric]
     90       if smoothing_std is not None:

KeyError: 'mae'
```

And also importing the necessary functions from tensorflow_docs (as showed on tutorial page) without any errors:

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I believe 'mae' is not included in the history, have you initialized the variable properly as the docs suggest?

Comment: Thank you. @tharina11 suggestion fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

replace 'mae' in your code with 'mean_absolute_error'.

Comment: Thanks, @tharina11! That worked! Could you elaborate more on why `mae` doesn't work? Is it a keras version issue?

Comment: It is not a keras error. I ran the exact code provided in the colab notebook (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) provided in the video description. Two cells before you plot this graph, there is an output table which is the data source of your plotting code. There I saw  'mean_absolute_error' instead of 'mae' (that is the parameter you are plotting in the graph). :)